# Calculus/Rate of Change

Tags: calculus

A circular oil slick spreads in such a way that its radius is increasing at a rate of 10 m/h. How fast is the area of the slick changing when the radius is 40 m? (In decimals)

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! The quality of your question can be greatly improved by letting other users know what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck

Answer (score 2):

The trick for *all such problems* is to first write down a formula that relates the two given variables, in this case the radius and the area of a circle.  We have $A = \pi r^2$.  If we differentiate this with respect to time (bearing in mind the chain rule), we get $\displaystyle \frac{dA}{dt} = 2 \pi r \left( \frac{dr}{dt} \right)$.

Now it's just a matter of plugging in known quantities.